# Internal Server Error on apache, but only on PHP files

Tags: php, apache

This is not a duplicate, this is a millionplicate, because I know there are like dozens of the same question in here, but none of them have the answer for my situation.

There we go:

I have apache, with the latest zend server. For some reason whenever i open a php project, it does not open, it says Internal Server Error.

I have changed the httpd.conf, have allowed permissions to the folder, and if i run php phpinfo.php (my test file), it will run the php file, but if i open on a browser, it wont.

The apache is running html files, but not PHP.

Any help on this?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 btw

Comment: I don't know offhand for Windows, but at least on Linux/OS X there is a different `php.ini` file for CLI than there is for Apache.  I would make sure that the Apache one doesn't contain any errors. (perhaps temporarily copy the CLI version to the Apache one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please be sure this command codes are in your apache httpconfig file

`LoadModule php5_module "c:/yourphpfolderr/php5apache2_2.dll"`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

`# configure the path to php.ini`

`PHPIniDir "C:/yourphpfolder"`

Comment: Just changed the directory, now i'm getting Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: your php5apache2.dll should be exits please open your apache folder and check it, Also you need to modify you php.ini

Comment: Ok sounds like i got it to work using WAMP. But i'll tag your answer as the correct one because i'm sure it would have worked if i  tried. (I'd need to restart my computer to try it, and i'm lazy...) Thanks for the help, cheers!